# Use nginx to convert a URL with parameters to pretty links, but at the same time allow PHP to access the parameters

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have an `index.php` file inside a directory on my server running nginx. It does some currency conversion calculations.

I need to be able to send a GET request to this file that includes 5 URL parameters.

Example:

https://example.com/conversion/index.php?countryfrom=US-United+States&countryto=IN-India&amount=123&amount_type=USD&recv_amount=INR

But … this is an ugly URL for humans, so I want to make it prettier, and therefore convert it to:

https://example.com/conversion/US-United-States/IN-India/USD/INR/123

I think I figured out this part (but it's possibly not the most elegant solution):

```
rewrite ^/conversion/index.php /conversion/$arg_countryfrom/$arg_countryto/$arg_amount_type/$arg_recv_amount/$arg_amount? last;
```

However … `index.php` needs to be able to read those variables, and it can’t if they’re stored as URL paths (at least I don't think so?), so somehow in the backend nginx needs to convert it back to `?countryfrom=US...` format.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: this with %2b    is no nice slug      use  only hyphens instead: (serch for SLUG to get more info )   https://example.com/conversion/US-United-States/IN-India/USD/INR/123      which leads me to a different question:   why do you need the country at all? - Use just the ISO code for the currency..

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig the "US-United-States" is the country code + country name. The "USD" is the currency code. A single country can have multiple currency codes. Good point about %2b, but that's not relevant to my nginx config problem ;)

Comment: `rewrite ... permanent`; corresponds to `return 301 ...` IIRC. Instead of 301, I would use 303 so that you can quickly change something (without caching the redirect). 301 to 308 are all redirects. Redirects are executed by the client or browser. This makes them visible to the client. I wouldn't please every BDU, but stick to the `?` and `&` parameters. KISS (for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ~ /conversion/(?<countryfrom>[^/]*)/(?<countryto>[^/]*)/(?<amount_type>[^/]*)/(?<recv_amount>[^/]*)/(?<amount>[^/]*)/?
    {
        alias /var/www/html/conversion/;
        index index.php;

        location ~* \.php$
        {
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/conversion/index.php;  # hard-coded
            # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;  # dynamic - unsure
            # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;  # dynamic - unsure
            # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;  # dynamic - unsure

            fastcgi_param countryfrom $countryfrom;
            fastcgi_param countryto $countryto;
            fastcgi_param amount $amount;
            fastcgi_param amount_type $amount_type;
            fastcgi_param recv_amount $recv_amount;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['countryfrom'];
# …
```

The advantage of named variables is that you do not mix them with variables from another scope, such as the http, server or location block.

Untested.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me at "do something with" lol. I'm a beginner with nginx config.

Comment: Both URL versions are included in the question. I'm not sure I follow ...

Comment: That's what I need help with. Everything I have so far is listed in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227100/discussion-between-kane-and-qrabno).

Comment: Updated. (So, if you have something that works (the version without the nice URL, for example) and you include it in the question, I'd be happy to adjust my answer accordingly. I mean your Nginx config. How should I know. Anyway, it sounded like you already had something that worked and just wanted to take the next step. Better? Totally untested.)

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why do you need the countries for a currency concerter but if you really need this use the ISO codes of the countries

https://example.com/conversion/US/IN/USD/INR/123

if not use the currencies only

https://example.com/conversion/USD/INR/123

and then rewrite this to
https://example.com/conversion/index.php?countryfrom=US&countryto=IN-&amount=123&amount_type=USD&recv_amount=INR

or   https://example.com/conversion/index.php?amount=123&from_cur=USD&to_cur=INR

Your rewrite rule is wrong.

You need an regex to analyze the pattern and rewrite it into the new URL

https://example.com/conversion/USD/INR/123

```
rewrite  ^/conversion/(\w{3})/(\w{3})/(\d*)$   /conversion/index.php?amount=$3&from_cur=$1&tocur=$2 last;
```

you can test your regex here: https://regex101.com/   (CAUTION: here you will have to escape the slashes with backslashes -  remove them again to use for apache/nginx)

more infos on Nginx rewriting
https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/

Comment: The PHP page displays information about the country as well as currency conversions. That's why the country code + name is passed in. I'm looking for the actual nginx config, since I'm not very familiar with writing it. So your answer doesn't help me, unfortunately.

Comment: I changed the answer and inserted a regex - you can change this to reflect all your desires and necessities.

Comment: When I tried your regex I get a 404 error. Does that `rewrite` line have to be inside a `location` block? Or can it just be in the `server` block?

Comment: Also FYI I needed to wrap the {} section in double quotes, to avoid the `[emerg] directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";"` error